# Switching to anaconda installation of python

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Python 2.7 on my computer awhile ago, and I believe I did not use Anaconda. I added Python 3.6 recently using an Anaconda environment, and am appreciating the benefits of using that. Is there a (somewhat) easy way to uninstall/reinstall Python 2.7 to be in the Anaconda environment as well so I can easily switch between them?

Update -- if I create an environment for Python 2.7 by doing the following, and Python 2.7 is already on my computer, does this reinstall Python 2.7?

```
$ conda create -n py2 python=2.7 anaconda
```

Comment: Just set the paths/environment (reorder or remove python2; probably uninstalling py2 will do). Anaconda-installer asked if it should set those paths, but you can do it manually too.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall Python 2.7 from your computer (not necessary though). After you have done so, you can use Anaconda to create a Python 2.7 virtual environment. This will allow you easily switch between Python 2.7 and 3.6.

To learn how you can create and manage virtual environments, check [this site](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/).